# Lagrange spectrum in diophantine approximation theory

Tags: number-theory, fractals, visualization, diophantine-approximation

**Context.**

[Hurwitz' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) states that for every irrational $\xi$, there is infinitely many rationals $p/q$ such that

$$\left\vert \xi-\frac pq\right\vert<\frac 1{q^2\sqrt 5}.$$

The number $\sqrt 5$ is the best constant possible here, in the sense that if $C>\sqrt 5$, then there exist irrationals $x$ such that

$$\left\vert x-\frac pq\right\vert<\frac 1{q^2C}$$

is **not** satisfied for infinitely many rationals $p/q$.

Now, let's define for a real number $x$, $L(x)$ to be the biggest constant such that

$$\left\vert x-\frac pq\right\vert<\frac 1{q^2L(x)}$$

for infinitely many $p/q$.

As it is said [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_spectrum), an equivalent definition would be

$$L(x)=\left(\liminf_{q\to\infty} q^2\vert x-p/q\vert\right)^{—1}.$$

For example,

$$L\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)=\sqrt 5,\quad L(\sqrt 2)=2\sqrt 2.$$

**The question.**

I am interested in the set

$$L:=\{L(x),\ x\in \mathbb R\}$$

which is called the *Lagrange Spectrum*.

We already know that the part of $L$ lying in $[\sqrt 5,3)$ is discrete, and the final part lying in $[F,+\infty)$ where

$$F=\frac {2\,221\,564\,096+283\,748\sqrt{462}}{491\,993\,569}\approx 4.5278$$

is Freiman's constant, is continuous. We also know that the part lying between those two parts as a fractal structure.

Since I have found it nowhere, I am asking here:

> Is there any graphical visualization of the set $L$? If not, would it be possible to make one?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Markoff_and_Lagrange_Spectra.html?id=nnvyBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @WillJagy Nice reference, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find graphical visualizations of Lagrange spectrum in this recent paper:

"Approximation of the Lagrange and Markov spectra"
Vincent Delecroix, Carlos Matheus, Carlos Gustavo Moreira
https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03773

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a picture of the Lagrange spectrum until sqrt(12) in the cover of the following book: https://worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/11965

[image]